# Playstore/Appstore Verify Purchase using a fuction in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

My app only has consumable and non-consumable in-app purchases (no subscriptions).

In order to verify a purchase is it ok to just store the token in the Firebase database and check if it exists as the verification logic? is this secure enough?

I know the backend function can integrate with play store/app store apis and verify the purchase. Do we need this complexity?